# How to parse through Twitch webpage and get list of online streamers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this has been done many times before but I am new to the coding scene (relatively new) and love to fiddle around with things. I've never managed to make anything really be functional, as in useful to me. I'm trying to make a chrome extension that shows a list of the online Counter Strike streamers that are currently streaming. I have no idea how to go about this. Is there a way through jQuery to go through [this](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Counter-Strike%3A%20Global%20Offensive) the page and take the first ~10 usernames it find?

I already know how to make the extension and the HTML and all that stuff. Just looking for functionality. I have a list at the moment on an HTML page. There's nothing in the list but I want to fill it with the online streamers. Solely doing this for a "fun" project to get some practice in. So not exactly looking for full answers but someone to point me in the right direction :D.

Completely lost on how to do this. Would regular expressions work?

Answer (score 0):

A mediocre way to do this would be to go into a Twitch page, look for the elements that repeat for each streamer and grabbing the inner HTML, that is, the information on who's streaming.

The proper way to do this would be to go through [Twitch's dev API](http://dev.twitch.tv/) and find information using their dedicated web services and information hooks. Consider it as a way for Twitch to get people invested in their website by providing them easy 'methods' to retrieve things like who's streaming, how many, etc.

I've never used it, but I'm sure it's simple and it's made for this situation.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I just have no idea how to write java script code to grab the inner html. Any idea of where I should start?

Comment: It's as simple as learning how to load a page, find an element on that page and `.innerHtml` or such.